Advanced conditions in power automate
I have a flow that is responsible for creating/updating a sharepoint list with files from an email.
Essentially, the flow runs when an email arrives, I check the day and time the email arrives, and I add the file to a sharepoint list based on the day and time.
I need the sharepoint list to have only certain files in it at a certain time. For instance:
Any email that arrives between Friday 6pm - Monday 9am need to be put in the same list
Any email that arrives between Monday 6pm - Tuesday 9am need to be put in the same list
Any email that arrives between Tuesday 6pm - Wednesday 9am need to be put in the same list
Any email that arrives between Wednesday 6pm - Thursday 9am need to be put in the same list
Any email that arrives between Thursday 6pm - Friday 9am need to be put in the same list

However, I am having an issue building out the condition. Here are the expressions I use to get the day and time:
int(formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/receivedDateTime'], 'HH'))

dayOfWeek(triggerOutputs()?['body/receivedDateTime'])

How would I go about crafting my condition?

What's the point of converting the time zone from UTC to UTC???

@teylyn I don't remember why I did that when I created it, but I removed it and edited my question

Your five conditions can be boiled down to two.
The time stamp is before 9 am or after 6 pm, or the weekday is Saturday or Sunday
or(
   or(
      less(hour(triggerBody()?['myDate']),9),
      greater(hour(triggerBody()?['myDate']),18)
   ),
   or(
      equal(dayOfWeek(triggerBody()?['myDate']),6),
      equal(dayOfWeek(triggerBody()?['myDate']),7)
   )
)

